# Prisma ORM: how to create a narrowed type from the result of findFirst()

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have a query which selects many tables:

```js
const distroAll = await prisma.distribution.findFirst({
        where: {
            id: distroId
        },
        include: {
            distributionPriorityGroups: {
                include: {
                    distributionPriorityGroupDeals: {
                        include: {
                            deal: {
                                include: {
                                    caps: {
                                        include: {
                                            timezone: true
                                        }
                                    },
```

(giving only a start of the query).

I want to go over the array `distributionPriorityGroupDeals` but I don't know how to define a partial type of this array.

What I'm doing now is

```js
type DistroAll = type DistroAll = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getDistroAll>>
async function workOnDeals(distroAll: DistroAll) {
   for (const {distributionPriorityGroupDeals} of distroAll) {
      //Do work
   }
}
```

So I send the entire distroAll object to the function, but actually I need only `distributionPriorityGroupDeals`.

How do I define or pick the type of `distributionPriorityGroupDeals` so that I can accept this in the function, something like that:

```
type DistroAll = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getDistroAll>>
type T = DistroAll[keyof DistroAll]["distributionPriorityGroupDeals"]

async function workOnDeals(distributionPriorityGroupDeals: T) {
  for (const deal of distributionPriorityGroupDeals) {
     // do work 
  }
}
```

(the above solution does not work as TS says `distributionPriorityGroupDeals` is of type `never`)